# FLutter, AppBar leading and action margin

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i modify leading and the action with IconButton margin/position in appbar? and what is the default margin for leading and `IconButton`
i can just pust the leading and the action in title with row but i want more cleaner code so i try with `leading:` `title:` `actions:` but the leading & actions is not in the line with the content in the body, the body has margin: 24 left and right. I'm having a hard time using `leading:` `title:` `actions:` from the start writing code in flutter

what i mean is to make the leading and action in the line with the body

[image]

this is my appbar code

```
appBar: AppBar(
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 1,
    titleSpacing: 0,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
    ),
    title: Text(
      'City Guide',
      style: Constants.textAppBar3,
    ),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/icon/icon_search.png',
          width: 24,
          height: 24,
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/icon/icon_save.png',
          width: 24,
          height: 24,
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/icon/icon_ticket.png',
          width: 24,
          height: 24,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: please upload proper image  for more clearity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IconButton` have size of icon(default 24) and have **padding(constrains-min)** itself to create a gesture space. With the size of Button is 48, it mean padding of IconButton is 12, your body padding is 24 so we need more 12, try wrap your leading by `Padding` with `left: 12`

**Example**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 1,
        titleSpacing: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
        ),
        title: const Text(
          'City Guide',
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: Colors.pink,
              size: 24.0,
              semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.local_activity,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 24.0,
              semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.radar,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 24.0,
                semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the built in padding in the IconButton widget. Use this on the IconButton.

```
IconButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
)
```

You can then modify the EdgeInsets as needed if you want a bit more padding.